# Please help to solve the following code

Tags: vb.net-2010

Iam Trying to capture page name in the url(localhost/fca/htp/home.aspx). This works for the first time. when page is loaded first time indexofdot takes the value 4 which is home. But when page gets refreshed or when we come back to home page again after visiting other pages it is taking the value 5 which is error.I tried page.ispostback to skip when refreshed but it is not working.
Thank you in advance

```
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(PageName) Then 'Probably the home page

        Dim PathComponents As String() = Request.FilePath.Split("/")
        Dim indexOfDot As Integer = PathComponents(PathComponents.Length - 1).IndexOf(".")
        If indexOfDot > -1 Then
            PageName = PathComponents(PathComponents.Length - 1).Remove(indexOfDot)
        End If
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your code in the page load method, or if you need to execute the function in page init, put some value in an hidden field at the first load, so that you can easily test the value of the hidden field in the Request.Form